# How to stop a simulation by timeout?

Tags: vhdl, simulation

I have manageg to implement a simulation timeout in VHDL. If processes are running longer the MaxRuntime they get 'killed'.

Unfortunately, this does not work the other way around. If my simulation is finished before MaxRuntime, everything is waiting for the last wait statement on MaxRuntime.

I found that it's possible to combine `wait on`, `wait for` and `wait until` statements into one.

My current code in snippets. A full example is quite to long...

```
package sim is
  shared variable IsFinalized : BOOLEAN := FALSE;

  procedure initialize(MaxRuntime : TIME := TIME'high);
  procedure finalize;
end package;

package body sim is
  procedure initialize(MaxRuntime : TIME := TIME'high) is
  begin
    -- do init stuff
    if (MaxRuntime = TIME'high) then
      wait on IsFinalized for MaxRuntime;
      finalize;
    end if;
  end procedure;

  procedure finalize;
  begin
    if (not IsFinalized) then
      IsFinalized := TRUE;
      -- do finalize stuff:
      --  -> stop all clocks
      -- write a report
    end if;
  end procedure;
end package body;

entity test is
end entity;

architecture tb of test is
begin
  initialize(200 us);

  process
  begin
    -- simulate work
    wait for 160 us;
    finalize;
  end process;
end architecture;
```

The wait statement is not exited if `IsFinalized` changed. My simulation runs for circa 160 us. If I set `MaxRuntime` to 50 us, the simulation stops at circa 50 us (plus some extra cycles until each process noticed the stop condition). When I set `MaxRuntime` to 200 us, the simulation exits at 200 us and not after 162 us.

- **How can I exit/abort the wait statement?**
- **Why can't I wait on a variable?**

*I don't want to use a command line switch for a simulator to set the max execution time.*

Comment: Dear **downvoter** please leave a comment so I can improve my question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot wait on a variable for the reasons given by user1155120. So, instead you need to use a signal. (A signal in a package is a global signal).

Unfortunately, even though the global signal is in scope, it still needs to be an output parameter of the procedure, which is ugly. Not only that, in your code, you will then be driving the signal from more than one place, this global signal needs to be a resolved type, eg std_logic. Which is also a bit ugly.

Here is a version of your code with the shared variable replaced by a signal, the boolean type replaced by a std_logic and the global signal added as output parameters:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

package sim is
  signal IsFinalized : std_logic := '0';

  procedure initialize(signal f : out std_logic; MaxRuntime : TIME := TIME'high);
  procedure finalize (signal f : out std_logic);
end package;

package body sim is
  procedure initialize(signal f : out std_logic; MaxRuntime : TIME := TIME'high) is
  begin
    -- do init stuff
    if (MaxRuntime = TIME'high) then
      wait on IsFinalized for MaxRuntime;
      finalize(f);
    end if;
  end procedure;

  procedure finalize (signal f : out std_logic) is
  begin
    if (IsFinalized = '0') then
      f <= '1';
      -- do finalize stuff:
      --  -> stop all clocks
      -- write a report
      report "Finished!";
    end if;
  end procedure;
end package body;

use work.sim.all;

entity test is
end entity;

architecture tb of test is
begin
  initialize(IsFinalized, 200 us);

  process
  begin
    -- simulate work
    wait for 160 us;
    finalize(IsFinalized);
    wait;
  end process;
end architecture;
```

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/VBK

Comment: Now you have the best of both worlds.

Comment: Good idea. But, there is a syntax error at line 23. It must read `if (isFinalized = '0') then`. Also a wait is missing after `finalize(...)` in line 46. Tested with GHDL and ModelSim.

Comment: @Martin Zabel It turns out that I was inadvertently relying on VHDL-2008, which was enabled, so the mysterious and optional ?? operator had come into play. It is better not to needlessly rely on VHDL-2008, so I have changed it. I've added the wait, too - I hadn't noticed that the simulation hadn't actually stopped!

Comment: I'm a bit unsure about the concurrent procedure call: `initialize(IsFinalized, 200 us);`. Now IsFinalized is in the sensitivity list, which worries me that the initialize procedure is called again once there is an event on IsFinalized.

Answer (score 4):

So it sounds like you want to terminate the simulation, either at time out, or at finished test prior to timeout.  It is correct that the simulator will stop when the event queue is empty, but that is pretty high do achieve, as you also experience.

VHDL-2008 has introduced [`stop`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=vhdl+2008+stop+statement) and [`finish`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=vhdl+2008+finish+statement) in the `std.env` package for stop or termination of simulation.

In VHDL-2002, a common way is to stop simulation is by an `assert` with `severity FAILURE`:

```
report "OK   ### Sim end: OK :-) ###   (not actual failure)" severity FAILURE;
```

This method for simulation stop is based on the fact that simulators (e.g. ModelSim) will usually stop simulation when an `assert` with `severity FAILURE` occurs.

Comment: The simulation package written by me , takes care to terminate every running process except for self stimulating entities like PLLs and DCMs :). I would like to implement this functionality in VHDL-93 and 2008. I have two packages, one for every VHDL version, so I could use `stop/finish` in the 2008 package. I know of `severity FAILURE`. Does it stop in every simulator?

Comment: You could also use a C foreign function to call exit with a non-error return value for earlier revisions of the VHDL standard. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 16.5 Standard environment package para 3. I'd do a fflush() first.

Comment: I ported my test to  VHDL-2008: waiting in a protected type's procedure causes a deadlock problem... So I'll need a better trick.

Comment: How did you notice the deadlock? IEEE 1076-2008 Dynamic elaboration "NOTE 2—If two or more processes access the same set of shared variables, livelock or deadlock may occur. That is, it may not be possible to ever grant exclusive access to the shared variable as outlined in the preceding item b). Implementations are allowed to, but not required to, detect and, if possible, resolve such conditions."  Even that's not portable.

Answer (score 3):

- How can I exit/abort the wait statement?

  Why can't I wait on a variable?

All sequential statements in VHDL are atomic.

A wait statement happens to wait until a resumption condition is met, waiting on signal events, signal expressions or simulation time.

What would you use to select the statement a process resumed at if you could exit/abort it? Would it resume? You'd invalidate the execution of the sequence of statements.  VHDL doesn't do exception handling, it's event driven.

And here it's worth remembering that everything that executes in simulation is a process, function calls are expressions and concurrent statements (including procedure calls) are devolved into processes potentially with super-imposed block statements limiting scope, during elaboration.

There's this basic difference between variables and signals (IEEE Std 1076-2008 Appendix I Glossary):

**signal**: An object with a past history of values. A signal may have multiple drivers, each with a current value and projected future values. The term signal refers to objects declared by signal declarations or port declarations. (6.4.2.3)

**variable**: An object with a single current value. (6.4.2.4)

You can't wait on something that doesn't have a future value, or a little more simply *variables don't signal* (from a dictionary - *an event or statement that provides the impulse or occasion for something specified to happen*).

Simulation is driven by signal events depending on future values. It defines the progression of simulation time. Time is the basis for discrete event simulation.

And about now you could wonder if someone would be telling you the truth if they were to claim VHDL is a general purpose programming language. How can it be while maintaining the ability formally specify the operation of hardware by discrete time events if you have the ability to break and resume a process arbitrarily?

And all this tells you is you might consider using signals instead of share variables.

Morton's stop and finish procedures are found in std.env.

Comment: I also tried a "global" signal declared in a package, but GHDL gives me an analysis error that a procedure can't access a signal: `signal "KillAll" is not a formal parameter`. I assume it must be an inout parameter. The VHDL book of [Ben Cohen](https://books.google.de/books?id=tWkfoAiXpuYC&pg=PA303&lpg=PA303&dq=vhdl+wait+until+for+timeout&source=bl&ots=8SW94-6P95&sig=2tyP9JT17qRkC9MfcVK9A0LxNfo&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiEs62-wOvKAhXCKg8KHQFlC3gQ6AEIPDAJ#v=onepage&q=vhdl%20wait%20until%20for%20timeout&f=false) lists wait statements also for variables... but my example code shows no effects.

Comment: While `wait on var1` results in an analysis error, `wait until (var1 = TRUE)` is accepted by GHDL.

Comment: Amazingly enough the same text is found on page 303 of the English version of Ben's book. There's an implied sensitivity list in for a wait until.  IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.2 Wait statement para 3 (in part) "...Each signal name in the sensitivity list shall be a static signal name, and each name shall denote a signal for which reading is permitted. If no sensitivity clause appears, the sensitivity set is constructed according to the following (recursive) rule:..."

Answer (score 1):

From a test automation point of view it's important to have a time-out that can force a test to a stop using stop/finish/assert failure. Even if your intention is to make everything terminate by not producing more events there is a risk that there is a bug causing everything to hang. If that happens in the first of your tests in a longer nightly test run you're wasting a lot of time.

If you use [VUnit](http://vunit.github.io) it would work like this

```
library vunit_lib;
context vunit_lib.vunit_context;

entity tb_test is
  generic (runner_cfg : runner_cfg_t);
end tb_test;

architecture tb of tb_test is
begin
    test_runner : process
    begin
      test_runner_setup(runner, runner_cfg);
      while test_suite loop
        if run("Test that hangs") then
          -- Simulate hanging test case
          wait;
        elsif run("Test that goes well") then
          -- Simulate test case running for 160 us
          wait for 160 us;
        end if;
      end loop;

      test_runner_cleanup(runner); -- Normal forced exit point
    end process test_runner;

    test_runner_watchdog(runner, 200 us);
end;
```

The first test case which hangs is terminated by the watchdog after 200 us such that the second can run.

[image: Time-out]

A problem that you may encounter when forcing the testbench to stop with the `test_runner_cleanup` procedure is if you have one or more additional test processes that have more things to do when the `test_runner` process reaches the `test_runner_cleanup` procedure call. For example, if you have a process like this

```
another_test_process: process is
begin
  for i in 1 to 4 loop
    wait for 45 us;
    report "Testing something";
  end loop;
  wait;
end process;
```

it will not be allowed to run all four iterations. The last iteration is supposed to run at 180 us but `test_runner_cleanup` is called at 160 us.

[image: Premature exit]

So there is a need to synchronize the `test_runner` and `another_test_process` processes. You can create a package with a global resolved signal to fix this (as discussed before) but VUnit already provide such a signal which you can use to save some time. `runner` is a record containing, among other things, the current *phase* of the VUnit testbench. When calling `test_runner_cleanup` it enters the phase with the same name and then it moves to the `test_runner_exit` phase in which the simulation is forced to a stop. Any process can prevent VUnit from entering or exiting its phases by placing a temporary lock. The updated `another_test_process` will prevent VUnit from exiting the `test_runner_cleanup` phase until it's done with all its iterations.

```
another_test_process: process is
begin
  lock_exit(runner, test_runner_cleanup);
  for i in 1 to 4 loop
    wait for 45 us;
    report "Testing something";
  end loop;
  unlock_exit(runner, test_runner_cleanup);
  wait;
end process;
```

[image: Exit lock]

Any number of processes can place a lock on a phase and the phase transition is prevented until **all** locks have been unlocked. You can also get the current phase with the `get_phase` function which may be useful in some cases.

If you're developing reusable components you should probably not use this technique. It saves you some code but it also makes your components dependent on VUnit and not everyone uses VUnit. Working on that :-)

DISCLAIMER: I'm one of the authors for VUnit.